# "execution reverted" Error when deploying Safemoon fork on Rinkeby

Tags: ether, contract-deployment, etherscan, contract-debugging

I keep getting this error message when trying to deploy a Safemoon fork. There's no other information provided.

Code is here

```
https://bscscan.com/address/0x8076c74c5e3f5852037f31ff0093eeb8c8add8d3#code
```

I'm using remix with metamask

I also tried to deploy this on BSC test net and got the same error message

Comment: maybe this contract depends on another contract and you need somehow to deploy it and change the address. just a guess I have no idea. Look at this line.. it does have a hardcoded address
 IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F);

Answer (score 2):

It's using pancakeswap Router mainnet address, you can find it in line 758,

**IUniswapV2Router02 _uniswapV2Router = IUniswapV2Router02(0x05fF2B0DB69458A0750badebc4f9e13aDd608C7F);**

You should change this address to Router address in BSC testnet,

#PancakeSwap on BSC testnet:

Factory: 0x6725F303b657a9451d8BA641348b6761A6CC7a17

**Router: 0xD99D1c33F9fC3444f8101754aBC46c52416550D1**